# passing a variable from class to class

Tags: python, class, variables, dictionary, game-engine

I'm trying to create a game-save file in python, using a dict which looks like this:

```
       user = {
        'Name': 'craig',
        'HP': 100,
        'ATK': 20,
        'DEF' : 10,
        'GOLD' : 300,
        'INV' : [0, pants],
        'GEAR' : [0, axe],
        'CityLevel' : 0,
        'BadAns': 0,
        }
```

I'm passing it through classes just like in [excercise 43 of learn python the hard way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex43.html)

the code in

"############

code here

#######"

works, but replacing all of that with 
     name = temp 
doesn't pass the 'user' variable along with the return like the current code does.

```
class User():
  def enter(self, user):

    def writing(self, user):
        pickle.dump(user, open('users.pic', 'a'))

    print "Is this your first time playing?"
    answer = prompt()

    if answer == 'yes':
        print "Welcome to the Game!"
        print "What do you want to name your character?"
        user['Name'] = prompt()
        writing(self, user)
        print "You'll start out in the city, at the city entrance, Good luck!"
        gamesupport.print_attributes(player)
        return 'City Entrance'
    elif answer == 'no':
        print "what is your character's name?"
        charname = prompt()
        temp = pickle.load(open('users.pic'))
        ######################################
        user['Name'] = temp['Name']
        user['GOLD'] = temp['GOLD']
        user['HP'] = temp['HP']
        user['ATK'] = temp['ATK']
        user['DEF'] = temp['DEF']
        user['GEAR'] = temp['GEAR']
        user['CityLevel'] = temp['CityLevel']
                    ############################################
        print user
        return 'City Entrance'
    else:
        print "we're screwed"
```

the 'print user' works as expected, and prints everything correctly even if i just use 'user = temp', but then the user variable isn't saved and passed on to the rest of the game

why is this and how can I fix it? having to type in each attribute line by line isn't good, because then I can't append anything to 'user' and have it save and load up again.

Comment: It seems like you meant to add some code, but then forgot to paste it. Can you include that? Otherwise I don't think there's enough context here to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to do with how Python references objects. Take a look at this example:

```
>>> test = {}
>>> test2 = test
>>> test2 is test
True
>>> def runTest(test):
...     print test is test2
...     test = {}
...     print test is test2
... 
>>> runTest(test)
True
False
```

As you can see, in the `runTest` function if you use `test = ...` the variable references a new dictionary. The way to solve this is to use the `update` method. This copies all values from the source dictionary into the target dictionary:

```
>>> source = {'a':'b', 'c':'d'}
>>> target = {'a':'g', 'b':'h'}
>>> target.update(source)
>>> print target
{'a':'b', 'b':'h', 'c':'d'}
```

Comment: This is exactly it! I've been working on this for two days now trying to figure out if it was something silly I've been doing, and I was getting to the point where I thought it was how python handled the variables.

Thanks so much!

Comment: It is worth noting that mutating values in the global scope rather than returning a new value is actually considered bad practice - side effects are much harder to understand as you read through code. A better version of your code would `return` your new dictionary and utilise that, making the flow of data through your program clearer.